# Issue when i remove objects in a map. I need to recall the function 3 times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button that call function findPrice. I need to call this function 3 times or more to delete all object that match price with priceSearch(the input value) i have the problem with bigs maps no witch 2 functions.

Json format:

```
[ { _id: 5c6c408dbec3ab457cf5bdfb,
    date: 2019-02-19T00:00:00.000Z,
    user: 5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee,
    positionDetail: [ { quantity: 2, price:22}, { quantity: 3, price:33}, { quantity: 5, price:43}],
    id: 50,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5c6c408dbec3ab457cf5bdfb,
    date: 2019-02-27T00:00:00.000Z,
    user: 5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee,
    positionDetail: [ { quantity: 3, price:33}, { quantity: 2, price:123}, { quantity: 2, price:11}],
    id: 51,
    __v: 0 }, ]
```

I think i have problem with the index of the map. I tryed to put i-- when i delete 1 obejct of the map but didn't work.

```
findPrice() {

    this.arrayOfObjects.forEach( (data, i) => {

        let searchIfExist= data.positionsDetail.findIndex(index1 => index1.price === priceSearch);

        if (searchIfExist=== -1) {

          this.arrayOfObjects.splice( i, 1 );

          i--;
        }

    });
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? And this doesn't make any sense "i have the problem with bigs maps no witch 2 functions." Witches ride broomsticks! ;-)

Comment: Most of the time you don't want to modify an array while looping through it. You need to use immutable array methods and return a new array. (filter in the answer below, map...etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `Array.filter`?

```
let filtered = this.arrayOfObjects.filter(data => data.positionDetail.price !== priceSearch);
```

Edit:

If you want to use splice, do not use it in `Array.forEach`. Use a for loop and loop backwards (to preserve the array splice index)

```
for (let i = arrayOfObjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arrayOfObjects[i].positionDetail.price === priceSearch) {
    arrayOfObjects.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Generally using `filter` is better performance-wise, since the original array is not modified.

## Edit 2:

`data.positionDetail` is an *Array*? Well... why didn't you say so :) Try this:

```
const filtered = this.arrayOfObjects.filter(data =>
  data.positionDetail.filter(
    priceData => priceData.price === priceSearch
  ).length !== 0
);
```

The inner filter filters `positionDetail` Array: if the result is empty, there is no price = priceSearch, so you discard the outer object.

Comment: very  very interesting I saw the examples of the function filter but i really didn't know that u can go to others levels with 2 filters. I tried to do that on the loop but didn't work because only filter the positionDetail not the object. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

USE array. filter or FindIndex where the price!== pricesearch and then splice that index using splice method.

Comment: you don't need to splice. filter returns a new array

Comment: Yes ForSure, But I have mentioned you can use array.filter 'OR' findIndex and then splice

Comment: i tryed to use filter but i had problem because is 2 levels objects of array what i mean. Is we have the main object and in positionsDetails we can have more position with prices. i want to delete the objects when the prices no match in any position of the array.